# Command line equivalent of Visual Studio Add New Page (WPF)

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, .net-core, terminal

In the WPF first desktop app [walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/getting-started/walkthrough-my-first-wpf-desktop-application), it uses Visual Studio to explain how to create a new page in a WPF project. I don't use Visual Studio, but I want to make an XAML Page file using the terminal. I can't just create a new file because it has prewritten code for a new Page similar to below:

```
<Page x:Class="ExpenseIt.ExpenseItHome"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="350" d:DesignWidth="500"
    Title="ExpenseIt - Home">

    <Grid>
        
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I checked the [`dotnet new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new) documentation and it says nothing about creating a new file. I know I can just have the default contents in a separate file which I can copy and paste but this seems like an inelegant workaround. Is there a command line argument or another way to get the Page WPF Template without Visual Studio?

## Edit

To be more specific on what I am looking for, I would like an XAML file and its corresponding `.xaml.cs` code-behind file with all the using statements. As suggested, I can use XamlReader, which I have tried, but I would preferably like a tool. XamlPadX is outdated and does not have the code-behind that I am looking for.

## Edit 2

This is my current code in the console app I am making:

```
        if (args[0].StartsWith("loadpage-"))
        {
            string className = args[0].Substring("loadpage-".Length);
            string xamlOutput = String.Join(
                Environment.NewLine,
                $"<Page x:Class=\"{className}\"",
                "xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"",
                "xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\"",
                "xmlns:mc=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006\"",
                "xmlns:d=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008\"",
                "mc:Ignorable=\"d\"",
                "d:DesignHeight=\"350\" d:DesignWidth=\"500\"",
                $"Title=\"\">",
                "<Grid>", "", "</Grid>",
                "</Page>");
            Console.WriteLine(xamlOutput);
        } 
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You must enter the argument in the following format: ");
            Console.Write("loadpage-CLASSNAME");
        }
```

Comment: How about  other tools like XamlPadX or KaXaml?

Comment: @DasiyTianMSFT Those don't accomplish everything I want to do and are quite outdated

Answer (score 0):

You could write a console application which uses command line arguments to receive the xaml content via pure text, or text file containing the content of the xaml page.
Load it using XamlReader in Main method of your program.cs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xamlreader?view=netcore-3.1